# Mage registry key "_singleton/[Extension_Model_Core]" already exists

Tags: php, magento

I removed a Magento extension manually via the server in order to see if it was causing blank pages on a site. I now get the following error while trying to access the admin panel:

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/[Extension_Model_Core]" already exists
```

I have so far:

- made sure all extension files were removed from their appropriate places
- cleared the cache (`rm -rf var/cache/*`)
- cleared the session (`rm -rf var/session/*`)
- disabled, cleared and reactivated compiler (`php shell/compiler.php --disable/clear/compile`)

The error persists. Note that I no longer have access to the admin panel so everything must be done via ssh/ftp.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the table core_resource and delete all related to that extension

Comment: @AlexColoma Thanks for the suggestion but there is no mention of the extension within the `core_resource` table. It wasn't actually causing the original issue (blank pages) so I've put the module files back. Though I am intrigued as to why this error would show after everything had been moved and the caches cleared.